# Odoo : Truncate result on list view

Tags: listview, odoo, odoo-11

I am working on Odoo 11.

I am looking for, truncate a tree/kanban view.
I would like to hide to my users the full list of my customers but if they find them with good informations by the search view, they can access to their form.

NTH : When the search is empty, I would like display the last seen customers by the login user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what kind of filter do you wanna apply I suggest you to start with the security record rules to be able to limit the records displayed with a domain matching the records you wanna show to your users.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/security.html#record-rules